# c# webbrowser scrape thousands of pages in one site failed

Tags: c#, web-scraping, console-application

I need collect data from a site "abc.com". the url is like "abc.com/city/a"; "abc.com/city/b"; "abc.com/city/c";..""abc.com/city/zzz"; totally like 2000+ pages. I am thinking use WebBrowser in a loop to get the data. But alway failed after 100 pages and get a blank error messagebox with title "message from webpage".
What is the proper way to do the job like this?

Comment: Unless you know the person running the site, you're likely to get blacklisted doing this.  You should ask the site for permission, maybe they can help you out via a Web Service or an API.

Answer (score 0):

You want a WebClient that sends requests and reads the response, although I'm not sure about the performance.

Comment: some js loading after page loaded. So I have to use webBrowser. The problem is most server wont let people connect/query that much.